# Asp.net Mvc 2: Repository, Paging, and Filtering how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, paging, filtering

It makes sense to pass a filter object to the repository so it can limit what records return:

```
var myFilterObject = myFilterFactory.GetBlank();
myFilterObject.AddFilter( new Filter { "transmission", "eq", "Automatic"} );
var myCars = myRepository.GetCars(myfilterObject);
```

**Key question: how would you implement paging and where?**  Any links on how to return a LazyList from a Repository as it would apply here?  Would this be part of the filter object?  Something like:

```
myFilterObject.AddFilter( new Filter { "StartAtRecord", "eq", "45"} );
myFilterObject.AddFilter( new Filter { "GetQuantity", "eq", "15"} );
var myCars = myRepository.GetCars(myfilterObject);
```

I assume the repository must implement filtering, otherwise you would get all records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implement paging/sorting in my service layer. I think some people would disagree with this, but it works great for me. Make sure your repository returns an IQueryable though.

```
public class ProductService
{
   private IRepository<Product> Products {get; set;}
```

public IEnumerable<ProductDto> GetProductsMatching(FilterCriteria criteria)
   {
      var products = Products.Query()
         .Where( // do filtering )
         .OrderBy( // order by )
         .Skip(criteria.PageSize * criteria.CurrentPage)
         .Take(criteria.PageSize);
      var dtos = products.Select( // do mapping );
     return dtos;
   }
}

How you return a LazyList/IQueryable depends on what ORM you are using. I am only familiar with NHibernate (use Linq to NHibernate) and Linq2Sql.

Comment: +1 for the thoughtful answer.  As an addition, I would suggest actually returning IEnumerable even if you plan on using IQueryable, since not all things support IQueryable.  If the object instance is an IQueryable, it'll still benefit from the late call to the db and so on, but you can switch to an impl.  that doesn't direclty support IQueryable w/o having to change anything that depends on the interface.

Comment: Would you have to do a big case statement on the criteria to match the fields in the where clause?

Comment: @Dr. Zim: Actually there are several dynamic sorting implementations available online. Here's one that looks good. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Article.aspx?aid=27834 You can also do this using C#'s built in expression builders, but it's a bit more complicated. It looks like you already have filtering figured out.

Comment: Here's an update since this still gets the occasional upvote. I've more or less abandoned this pattern in favor of plugging my database directly into my controllers and doing filtering, paging and sorting there. The service + dtos + repository abstractions were too much overkill for the kinds of projects I routinely work on. My advice is to consider the simplest pattern that gets the job done.